# Calculate First Quartile of a dataset using data.frame() where row numbers have been removed in R

Tags: r, dataframe, quartile

```
mylist2<-list(as.numeric(c(1:20)),(c(1:20)**2),sqrt(c(1:20)))

iData<-data.frame(do.call(cbind,mylist2))

print(iData,row.names=FALSE)

quantile(iData$X1,iData$X2,iData$X3,c(0.25,0.25,0.25))
```

I want to display these column combined vectors its first quartile, but I am stuck on this

Comment: You could simplify the creation of `mylist2`. Try `mylist3 <- list(1:20, (1:20)**2, sqrt(1:20)); all.equal(mylist2, mylist3)`. The only difference between the two is that `mylist2[[1]]` is of class `numeric` and `mylist3[[1]]` is of class `integer`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to get the quantiles of each column separately, I would recommend using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
iData %>%  summarize_all( ~ quantile(.x, probs = 0.25))
```

or equivalently

```
summarize_all(iData, ~ quantile(.x, probs = 0.25))
```

A base method would use `sapply`:

```
sapply(iData, function(x) quantile(x, probs = 0.25))
```